How can I make a `tikzpicture's` coordinates react to TeX `dimensions`?
Further to the question I posted yesterday and received [an excellent answer answer ]2 regarding shading a block, I changed the code I was using (from just LaTeX code, using boxes etc) to tikz, using remember picture, overlay. I haven't used tikz for a long time and have a simple question. Must all values in a coordinate be TeX registers? Can values saved in \defs be used? If I want to add to this value within a coordinate do I need to use \dimexpr?
Please comment the line for includegraphics and code will use rules. Do not use example-image-a as its aspect ratio is wrong for this type of layout.
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc}
\graphicspath{{./images}{./images/header/}}
% mock
\long\def\savedtitle{The Genetics\\ Template}
\setcounter{chapter}{13}
\newlength\horline
\setlength\horline{17cm+2.5cm}
\NewDocumentCommand{\geneticsa}{}
{\tikzset{lines/.style={line width=2pt,line cap=rect,thechaptercolor}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% top lines
\coordinate[xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm](a) at (current page.north west);
\coordinate[xshift=\horline,yshift=-2cm](b) at (current page.north west);
\coordinate[xshift=1cm,yshift=-28cm](c) at (current page.north west);
\coordinate[xshift=\horline,yshift=-28cm](d) at (current page.north west);
%\node(d) at(0cm,17){};
\draw[lines](a)--(b);
\draw[lines](a)--(c);
\draw[lines](c)--(d);

\begin{scope}[blend mode=screen]
\shade[bottom color=thechaptercolor, top color=black] (-2,-15) rectangle (17.5,-13cm);
\shade[left color=thechaptercolor, right color=black] (-2,-15) rectangle (17.5,-11cm);
\end{scope}
% gray strip at end
\shade[bottom color=white, top color=black!80] (17.5,-15) rectangle (17,-11);
% text
\node[lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily, yscale=2.5] at (16,-14.5) [left]{CHAPTER CONCEPT};
\node[lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily,yscale=2.5,xscale=1.75,right] at (-2,-14.5) {\thechapter};
\node[above] at (13/2,-15) {\myrule};
% \node[above] at (13/2,-15) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{\image}}; %comment to see rules
\node[above] at (-1cm,-8){\bfseries\Large\sffamily\color{thechaptercolor} \chaptername}; 
\node[above,anchor=west,text width=4cm] at (-2cm,-18){\bfseries\Large\sffamily\color{thechaptercolor} \savedtitle}; 
\node[right] at (2cm,-20cm){\parbox{10cm}{\lipsum[3]}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}

\begin{document}
\newpage\null
\newpage
\definecolor{thechaptercolor}{HTML}{90D228}
\def\image{fashion-05} \def\myrule{\rule{10cm}{15cm}}
\geneticsa
\newpage
\definecolor{thechaptercolor}{HTML}{991B1E}
\def\image{fashion-04} \def\myrule{\rule{10cm}{13cm}}
\geneticsa

\end{document}



example-image-10x16 should have a similar aspect ration as the images you show.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Thanks good to know.

Your includegraphics line is hard to spot: please make it more visible for feedback. // You can use cm, pt etc. as units, like \node at (1cm, 15pt) {};. // You can use macros, see e.g. here for \def https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724299/245790. However, \newcommand almost always works with Tikz and is preferred. // Storage usually happens, and is sufficient, via naming, as you did with (a) etc. // I recommend using a bit more indenting (structured programming). To shorten your option lists, define and use styles, e.g. \begin{tikzpicture}[short/.style={...}, ...].

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is best though to use the rules, as I wanted to show the difference in the layouts, and the need to use registers to generalize the template for different paper sizes and image aspect ratios.

@yannisl If you think rules are best, then use rules in your example. However having to first modify your code before being able to even compile it, is inconvenient.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz My apologies for the inconvenience. I thought adding a % was not a big deal.

@MS-SPO thanks so basically the answer is yes?

"Yes" to what ,please?

is this what you mean? to calculate dimensions inside a coordinate, use braces e.g. ({\mylength-\myotherlength},{3pt+5cm}) or whatever. the braces trigger pgfmath parsing.

please link relevant earlier questions. otherwise people have to go to your profile, sort your questions by time, find this one somewhere in the (possibly long) list and then pick (hopefully) the one from the day before the date of this one.

if possible, I would avoid blend mode. the results can look fantastic, but rendering is unpredictable, as is printing. to quote the manual: Blending is a rather “advanced” feature of pdf. Most renderers, let alone printers, will have trouble rendering blending correctly. (page 355) you could render it to something like png and include as an external image, so you're not relying on the printer/viewer to interpret the instructions correctly.

@cfr Added the link, I originally used an image, but prefer the blending and understand the limitations of some pdf readers.  All the colors come from a small package providing about 20 palettes. I will add an option in the key-value list, for  users to use their own image if they wish.

@cfr My question was if I could do this {\mylength-\myotherlength+1cm} but I will try and use the curlies as you pointed out.

@yannisl yes, if you use it somewhere pgfmath will parse it. that should work fine as-is in a coordinate spec since it already uses braces. different point: the approach you're using here will significantly slow compilation if, say, the image is rendered for each chapter and there are many chapters. if your users use the external library, they will need to disable externalisation locally. (and you also can't reduce compilation time that way.) it does not take adding too much of this stuff to slow compilation to a crawl on documents of, say, 100 pages or more. maybe you know this already.
